# Getting "viewEncapsulation is not defined" when adding Component in Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Getting error below when adding component with CLI.
Version:
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.21
node: 6.4.0
os: win32 x64

> D:\GIT#####>ng g component test
>    installing component   create
>   src\app\test\test.component.css   create
>   src\app\test\test.component.html   create
>   src\app\test\test.component.spec.ts   create
>   src\app\test\test.component.ts viewEncapsulation is not defined (Error
>   in blueprint template:
>   D:\GIT\PartnerOrders2\node_modules\angular-cli\blueprints\component\files__path____name__.component.ts),

Anyone have an idea how to solve?

Comment: Perhaps you're missing an import? Please post the code that causes the error.

Comment: This is just a "add component", can't share the whole app-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug in the angular-cli.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3264

Answer (score 0):

Add

> import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';